# I used a function and the return value is different from what the function actually returns when I check the return value

Tags: python, function

[image: function problem]

```
def playerguess(guess):
    guess=0
    while guess not in [1,2,3]:
        guess=int(input('Guess 1,2 or 3:      '))
    return guess

playerguess(guess)
print(guess)
```

I tried to make the guess=1 and the function made it to 1 but when i checked the guess value it's 0

Comment: Do you have a different cell where you defined `guess` previously? The code produces a `NameError` when I try to run it.

Comment: i didnt have i thought it's just a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

first guess is a local variable or a global variable if it is a global variable use declare outside of the function scope and use global keyword in the function playerguess().

I'm assuming that **guess** is not a  global variable so the second. snipped that could solve your issue.

second see that while is checking that guess values is in the array [1,2,3] and you have declare and assigned guess with 0 you always will received 0 as return values because guess variable.

something simple you could do is using flags variable:

```
def playerguess():
    guess=0
    cap = True
    while cap:
        guess=int(input('Guess 1,2 or 3:      '))
        if guess not in [1,2,3]:
            cap = False
    return guess

g= playerguess()
print(g)
```

Comment: The second part of OP's code is correct. No need for a flag (I'd have used a set though).

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't handle arguments passed in to functions the way you are expecting. It passes arguments by assignment, which is *different* than pass-by-reference in C++ or Java. Importantly, you can't change the value of an argument (by rebinding it, rather than mutating it in place) and see that change outside of the function.

Here's a simpler example that doesn't confuse things with a return value:

```
def foo(x):
    x += 1

y = 1
foo(y)
print(y)
```

This code prints `1`, since the `foo` function can't rebind the variable `y` in the global namespace. The `+=` operator in the function only rebinds `x`, which is a local variable. You can remove the function entirely, and do the assignment, just like the interpreter does:

```
y = 1
x = y    # this is equivalent to passing y as an argument to foo
x += 1   # this is equivalent to the code in the function
print(y) # prints 1
```

The only substantive difference between this example and your code is that you're using the same name for the global variable and the local variable in your function. That can work, since they're different namespaces.

Probably you don't want to be passing any arguments to your `guess` function. Just get rid of it, and assign the value returned by the function to something.

```
guess = playerGuess()
```

Comment: thank you so much. here i made some notes from what you said. i hope i understood them right =)

`def foo(x):
    x += 1 #x plus 1
    print(x) #x=2
    print(y) #y=1
y = 1
foo(y) #x=y NOT y=x
print(y) #y=1`

Comment: It's very hard to read unformatted code in a comment here, but I think you've got the right impression. Calling a function with an argument assigns that argument's value to the local variable used for that argument in the function. Reassigning the variable again later in the function body doesn't change the outer value.

Comment: sorry this is my first stack overflow post. learning the formatting *peace
Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, we were all new here at one time. Take the [tour] if you haven't yet, it will explain a bit about how the site works.